# How to implement the event handler for a MFC CEdit ON_EN_SETFOCUS?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm just maintaining some MFC C++ code and I have a screen with many `CEdit` objects.

I want to implement the `OnFocus` event for all of then but write only one method to treat the event.

To do that I would need to know the `CEdit` ID that fired the event but it looks like the implementation of the `OnFocus` event in MFC does not have this as a parameter (compared to some other events like `OnCtlColor` that has `CWnd*` object as a parameter).

I just refuse to believe that I have to implement a small method for each single `CEdit` passing its ID to the main method that will do what I want!. If that's the only solution, shame on you MFC!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ON_CONTROL_RANGE` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3sz709f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) exists exactly to allow mapping single handlers to the same event on multiple controls.

First you need to ensure that your control IDs are sequential.
Then in the header you need to declare a handler which takes the control ID as a parameter:

```
afx_msg void OnSetFocusMulti(UINT ctrlId);
```

This allows you to distinguish the sender control in your handler if you need it.

Now you need to add this to message map, instead of bunch of `ON_EN_SETFOCUS(IDC_EDIT1, &CMyDlg::OnSetfocus)`:

```
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(EN_SETFOCUS, IDC_EDIT1, IDC_EDIT_X, OnEnSetFocusMulti)
                      ^           ^          ^             ^
//       notification code | first ctrl | last ctrl |   the handler
```

Other message map macros are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9k6yh5b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, works, thanks a lot! Had a big manual work to sort the IDs out but once I done it, main source got much neater!

Comment: glad to hear it. Yes, it is sometimes really the pain in the ass to handle the IDs, especially if multiple people on project change them manually and logic relies on them being sequential.